# problem with uniqueKey in solr

Tags: solr

I am new to solr, while creating the indexes i am attaching string to database table id

my field in schema.xml as follows

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

and i am passing 'GROUP1' for id, but it is storing [B@1e090ee like this.

How could i store the same value(GROUP1) instead of [B@1e090ee ?

Please help

Comment: where do you see `[B@1e090ee`?

Comment: <str name="id">[B@1e090ee</str> in the results i am getting.

Comment: I am using CONCAT('GROUP',group_id) as id in the query, then it is converting to binary format. How to stop this conversion? Please help.

Comment: are you using dataimporthandler? have you tried not using it, and see if you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer by using dataimporthandler i am getting this problem, because of CONCAT function in the query. I am indexing multiple tables so i need to generate a unique key which can represent the tables, example GROUP1,BLOG1 like this.So i am appending BLOG,GROUP strings to the primarykeys of each tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is group_id string or some numeric data type?
If it's not string you need to [cast it to char before concatenation](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,127487,127487#msg-127487) with appropriate encoding.

Also add encoding (that matches your MySQL db encoding) parameter to dataSource tag, like this:

```
<dataSource 
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://host/dbname" 
    batchSize="-1" 
    user="username" 
    password="password" 
    readOnly="true" 
    autoCommit="true" 
    encoding="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: So which one was it, the cast or dataSource encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Which DB are you using?
Do you see the correct values when you execute your query directly in your db?

IMHO, the problem has to be either with `DataImportHandler` or you actually have values like that ([B@1e090ee) in your `group_id` field.
Have you checked that `encoding` param in your `dataCofig's dataSource` is the same as your db's encoding?

Can you post your `dataConfig` file?

Comment: I posted my dataconfig file. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

@mbonaci

I am using mysql database.

when i execute the same query, the results are coming fine

the following is my data config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://host/dbname" batchSize="-1" user="username" password="password" readOnly="true" autoCommit="true" />
  <document name="products">
        <entity name="item" query="select group_id,group_title,description,DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ') as createdDate,group_status,CONCAT('GROUP',group_id) as id,'GROUP' as itemtype  from collaboration_groups where group_status=1 ">
            <field column="id" name="id" />
            <field column="group_id" name="itemid" />
            <field column="itemtype" name="itemtype" />
            <field column="group_title" name="fullName" />
            <field column="description" name="description"/>
            <field column="createdDate" name="createdDate"/>
        </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```